# Volver invisible un JPanel y hacer visible otro

Tags: java, netbeans, java-swing

Tengo un problema al hacer visible un panel luego de volver invisible otro panel.

*Este es mi JFrame, el cual contiene un `JPanel` que a su vez contiene estos 3 `JButton` como pueden apreciar:*

[image: captura de pantalla 1]

*Para que tengan una idea mas clara de lo que hago:*

[image: captura de pantalla 2]

Este es el metodo que uso en cualquiera de los 3 botones para hacer desaparecer el de inicio y hacer aparecer cualquier otro.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    panelInicio.setVisible(false);  
    panelPrimalidad.setVisible(true);  
    panelSubconjuntos.setVisible(false);  
    panelKColoreable.setVisible(false);  
}
```

El resultado en ejecución es el siguiente después de presionar cualquier de los botones:

[image: captura de pantalla 3]

Y la estructura de todos mis `JPanel` *(diferentes al de Inicio)* es esta:

[image: captura de pantalla 4]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me gustaría ver como has implementado los otros paneles, ya que no estoy acostumbrado a trabajar con herramientas visuales (El árbol), pero a ojo diría que tus otros tres paneles no tienen padre, deberías agregarlos al JFrame y hacerlos invisibles inmediatamente.

Algo así...

```
jframePadre.add(panelKColoreable);
jframePadre.add(panelSubconjuntos);
jframePadre.add(panelPrimalidad);
panelKColoreable.setVisible(false);
panelSubconjuntos.setVisible(false);
panelPrimalidad.setVisible(false);
```

Si los paneles no tienen frame padre no se podrán mostrar.

Comment: Gracias, esto me ayudo.

Answer (score 1):

¿Qué tal? puedes intentar con lo siguiente.

Crea tus paneles, crea tu Jframe. Dentro de la clase Jframe crea un objeto de cada uno de los paneles:

```
ClaseObjetoPanel objetoCreado;
//dentro del constructor del frame coloca lo siguiente: 
public constructor(){
this.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
this.pack();
}
```

Ahora en el método del evento click o action del botón coloca esto:

```
public .....action(){
try{
    getContentPane().removeAll();
    objetoCreado = new ClaseObjetoPanel();
    this.add(objetoCreado,BorderLayout.CENTER);
    this.pack();
    maximizar();
}catch(Exception e){
   e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Creamos el método que maximiza el elemento.

```
public void maximizar(){
    this.setExtendedState(MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
}
```

Saludos.